# Does auth0 support logging in to Azure AD using the Microsoft Authenticator App?

Tags: react-native, authentication, azure-active-directory, auth0

We have an auth0 App with an Enterprise Connection for Azure AD configured. The Azure AD has Conditional Access policies in place that only allow logins from so-called managed devices. A managed device in Azure AD is a device that is registered in Azure AD for a specific user. To prove to Azure AD that a login request comes from a managed device, the login has to happen via Microsoft Authenticator App.

So this means, in our React Native mobile app, we would like to have to following login flow:

Mobile App => Login => auth0 Login page => Click on "Login with Azure AD" => Microsoft Authenticator App opens => Satisfy all the conditional access policies => User logged in successfully.

Is this supported by the auth0 react native SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two things need to be fulfilled, First, auth0 react native SDK must complying with a Conditional Access policy per this [guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-conditional-access-dev-guide) once that's completed and then in the second place, you must have managed device from which you need to access your application so that above scenario would work with Azure AD in place of conditional access.